# Subtract two dataframe with the same name different index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

There's two dataframes, all the colnames are the same but the index is different.
I've tried several ways but I've been getting `NaN`. I'm guessing it is because it's trying to match the index but I am stuck.

I've tried:

```
df1.ix['Norm']-df2.ix['Norm']
df1 - df2.ix['Norm']
df1.astype(float) - df2.astype(float)
```

would like something like this

```
df1 - df2[df1.column.names]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you *don't want* index-aligned arithmetic, get rid of the indexes. You can subtract the numpy arrays to the same effect:

```
(df1.values - df2[df1.column.names].values)
```